# Terminated due to memory issue TLViewHierarchyTool checkUIView:block: loop

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, allocation

I am presenting a view controller and for some reasons [randomly 1/2] I get loop.

I just try to debug, and without any help full information. All methods are calls as usual. You could see the screen shot below from Allocation instrument

After opening a view controller app is freeze and after 10-15 seconds i get message in console: `Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need check out the SwizzleManager and HierarchyTool, just make sure everything is right with what did using runtime, here is method exchange. What I see is, you missused the HierarchyTool here. Maybe!

Comment: hi, thanks for answer, how could I check SwizzleManager? is not in my project

Comment: The TLSwizzleManager is not in your projects? you mean its a kind of system tool ?

Comment: alright forget it, just comment out the all the code in the presented controller, and see if that crash will happen, if not, check the code all related will view creation.

Comment: yes, i made search by the project and nothing common

Comment: its in your screen shot image